# What is present in a .deb file?

Tags: deb

I downloaded google-chrome for Linux, it got downloaded as a .deb file in downloads folder. I changed the current directory to the downloads folder and ran "google-chrome" in terminal. It started google chrome, but the issue is that .deb file is not a script(as I understand). Then how did the terminal understand that the 'google-chrome' command meant to start it? Commands like emacs...etc are already built-in. What about this command which is new to bash? How did it recognise it?

Comment: [One of the answers](http://askubuntu.com/a/282755/25656) starts with "*You probably already had google-chrome installed on your computer.*" Otherwise, there's no way that running `google-chrome` from a terminal would do what you feel it did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First a few basics:**

When you run a command on your terminal, you enter the name of a *file*, (which should be executable): if you enter a simple name e.g. `emacs`, the system searches a number of directories for a file with such name. This list of directory is your `PATH` (i.e. it is stored in a variable named PATH). you can see its contents by typing `echo $PATH`. (As a side note, these commands are not *built-in* like you said in your question... but some are, for instance `ls`, which don't have any executable file, but is directly executed by the shell)

Alternatively, you can enter a more complex filename, which include the directory :  `/usr/bin/emacs`, or event relative pathnames ! For instance, if you want to run the program in the file `myprog`, residing in your user directory, enter `./myprog` (`.` meaning *current directory*)

**Now back to your question:**

When installing software, the system has to take care of putting everthing in the right place, so you can find it later on... It is what the *package manager* does : it takes an archive (.deb file), open it, and basically, put the files in the right places.

In conclusion, you have to open your .deb file with the package manager.

```
cd ~/Downloads
dpkg -i google-chrome.deb
```

or, event better, install it through the software center.

Answer (score 6):

You probably already had google-chrome installed on your computer.

A deb file contains all the necessary files to install it with *dpgk* (as root):

```
dpkg -i <your-google-chrome-deb-file>.deb
```

*dpkg* will copy binaries to you binary files location and then the command *google-chrome* will be available in your shell. If you didn't do this nor used an apt-get to install google chrome, I guess it means that google chrome was already present on your system.

If you want to see what the deb fils contains, you can use:

```
dpkg --contents <file>.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

There are chromium and chrome if I'm not mistaken! It could be any one of those you already install.